# Detect format Date

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there a way, a good way, to test if a string than I want to transform in `DateTime` is `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy` ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10):

No, because it could be both. Is 11/10/2010 November 10th or October 11th?

Yes, in *some* cases (if one number is above 12) it will be unambiguous - but I think it's better to force one format or the other. If you just treat anything which *can* be done as MM/dd/yyyy that way, and move on to dd/MM/yyyy if it fails (or the other way round) then you'll get some very surprised users.

If this is part of a web application or something similar, I would try to make it completely unambiguous by using month *names* instead of numbers where possible.

Comment: Force ok, but for display is the first to send to database is the second

Comment: It's essentially an impossible problem, but most folks want to enter a simple date - 10/11/1970 - when asked for their birthday, and not be forced to spell out a month. I suppose you could assume a particular format, though geolocation or something, and then display a long-format preview of the date using that format with a client-side script.

Comment: @Kris-I: You shouldn't be formatting the `DateTime` *at all* to send it to the database. You should be sending it *as* a `DateTime` in a query parameter. That way you can't mess it up. For parsing user input, just use `DateTime.TryParseExact` specifying just the single accepted format.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you could try both when parsing:

```
DateTime result;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
    "05/10/2010",
    new[] { "MM/dd/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy" }, 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out result)
)
{        
    // successfully parsed date => use the result variable
}
```

Comment: Works only for unambiguous case, otherwise the first choice will be picked. (05/10/2010 could be October 5, 2010 or May 10, 2010)

Comment: Yes, there could be ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

This problem will exist until all accepts and uses the ISO way. I'm a Swedish programmer working a lot with American and English clients and it's surprisingly hard to get these clients to use the standardized date format.

[ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/support/faqs/faqs_widely_used_standards/widely_used_standards_other/date_and_time_format.htm) - Use it!

Comment: I always try to use iso date formats where I can. No ambiguity in them. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DateTime.ParseExact and DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

```
string date1 = "24/12/2010";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
bool dt1Valid = false;
try
{
    dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "dd/MM/yyyy", provider);
    dt1Valid = true;
}
catch
{
    dt1Valid = false;
}
```

Comment: Why would you show code using ParseExact when you're aware of TryParseExact? You simply shouldn't use ParseExact if you're just going to catch the exception and move on.

Comment: Not to mention that this code will fail, as TryParseExact() returns boolean value...

Comment: @Pawel Dyda: but he isn't using TryParseExact, so it will not fail.

Comment: @jgauffin: you haven't seen this code prior to modification :) Now it is more or less OK.